# What is the best way to load large amount of data to SQL Server Express

Tags: .net, sql-server-express

I've got text file which I need to parse and save to SQL Server Express DB. After parsing (which is now done in .NET 4.0 app), I've got about 300 000 records. Which is the best way/best practice to process this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the data in a .NET application: [SqlBulkCopy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder why is SqlBulkCopy better than bunch of INSERT commands in cycle?